# What is the most popular reporting services solution available

Tags: sql-server-2008

Are there any alternative to the reporting services from sql server?
I could not find any thing online of production use. Need the experts to answer here . Would love it, if sarcasm did not seep in

There is a team who is running a solution where they are running in to multiple security issues due to the setup where reporting server database is in a separate machine and the reporting service is in another machine. I am not asking for any fixes but rather what would be a viable alternative to sql-server in the industry today which allows the following in a Windows environment

1. Domain joined users to login
2. scaled deployment of servers
3. SSL security for the report managers

Comment: Why is it a down voted question?

Comment: So a typo is what is causing it. I am genuinely asking for help. Sad, that If I lose the reputation i will not be allowed to ask questions for a long time. This has been a headache over the past few weeks.

Comment: Your asking us to find or recommend a tool which is off-topic on SO, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: That can happen but if you answer a couple of question you'll be back on track quickly.

Comment: Yep , saw that . And now I am barred from asking that question. All I know is, if you could comment once before giving a -1 I could have still used this site. I am now adding myself to the team of folks who are not using SO

Comment: Given that it's an official MS product and part of SQL Server, I find it very hard to believe that Reporting Services cannot do the 3 things that you want. I suggest you ask a new question along the lines of "I tried to get Reporting Services to do X, but it gave error message Y".

Comment: you should have posted to http://serverfault.com/ as stackoverflow is for developers (and not products), and serverfaults is more for architects / supervisors.

Comment: And developers hate other developers who ask silly question (from their point of view).

Comment: Note: Reporting services in SQL2008 works only in INTERNET EXPLORER.... Official product or not official product.

Comment: All I am saying is, point me to that - there are folks who live and breathe SO , but then there are folks like who want this to a usable site and keep it so but the learning curve comes at a cost. By sending a -1 for me, I am barred from asking questions. I have genuine questions for a lot of different developer points. Looks like giving -1 gives you a demi god feeling here. I am passionate about SO , but this question jails are increasingly becoming painful. Many of my friends agree to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting services in Sharepoint integration mode is the pushed solution from Microsoft.

But reporting services in standalone mode on a separate machine works perfectly, if you have basic knowledge of IIS.

Or I can fix it for you through tse.

cheers.